# How to set propety which type is Enum based on the integer value of the Enum

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, enums

I am working on an `ASP.NET MVC4` application using `EF 5` and `Code First`. One of my entities looks like this :

```
public enum PageTypes
{
    LinkPage = 10,
    FileListPage = 20,
    TableValuePage = 30
}
public class Page
{
    public int PageID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public PageTypes Type { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

in my view I have dropDown where these values are hardcoded (taken from a viewmodel):

```
public class PagesViewModel
{
    public PageViewModel()
    {
        TypeOfPage = new List<ListItem> { 
                     new ListItem { Text = "LinkPage ", Value = "10" }, 
                     new ListItem { Text = "FileListPage ", Value = "20" },
                     new ListItem { Text = "TableValuePage ", Value = "30" } };
    }

    //some other properties
    public string SelectedValue { get; set; }
    public List<ListItem> TypeOfPage { get; set; }
}
```

and the actual visualization in the view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m[i].SelectedValue, new SelectList(Model[i].TypeOfPage, "Value", "Text")})
```

So when I get the model in my controller how can I actually set the `Page` Type based on the `SelectedValue` from the ViewModel :

```
new Page { //other properties.., Type = ???? }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's deceptively simple:

```
var enumValue = (EnumType)integer;
```

So in your case, the selected value from your drop down will be a `string`, so first you will need to `int.Parse` it to an integer, then do your cast as above to put it in your property assignment.

```
new Page { Type = (PageTypes)integerFromDropDown, ... }
```

Comment: Nice and simple. Thanks. I use this `Type = (PageTypes)Convert.ToInt32(model[i].SelectedValue)` how do you find it?

Comment: Yeah that'll work! You may want to split it out into variables to make it easier to debug. You say `Tomayto`, I say `Tomarto`; you say `Convert.ToInt32`, I say `int.TryParse` - same result :)